# Google Calendar API in UI ignoring scopes

Tags: javascript, google-api-client

I've implemented Google Calendar API. It works well. When I allow calendar integration in my app it asks for permissions to access calendars and everything works perfectly.

However, after a week or so the permissions just disappear.

```
api.client.init({
  apiKey: API_KEY,
  clientId: CLIENT_ID,
  discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
  scope: SCOPES,
}).then((data) => {
  resolve();
```

I can see in the network tab that the request is passing correct scopes.

But the response from Google misses the calendar scopes.

Scope sent:

```
scope: openid profile email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
```

Scope recieved:

```
scope: "email profile openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
```

The only way how to make it work again is to remove permissions to my app in the google account and start the whole process again.

It drives me crazy. I triple checked everything. Any ideas are hugely appreciated.

Some more info if it helps:
It's happening in my localhost. It's all allowed in Google API.
I use Google Firebase for auth process in my app.

Comment: What you pass in scope?

Comment: Hi Nadeem, const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';